# Simple log-in to system

Tags: java, beginner, mvc, swing, authentication

I am fairly new to the MVC paradigm and I am working with Swing at the moment. To test my understanding of MVC, I have written this simple program used to login in to a system. I was hoping someone could review what I have done so far and let me know if it follows MVC rules and best practices.

The View:

```
public class LoginScreen extends JFrame implements Observer {
private JLabel lblTitle, lblUsername, lblPassword;
private JTextField txtVanReg;
private JPasswordField txtPassword;
private JPanel pnlCenter, pnlNorth;
private JButton btnLogin, btnCancel;
private final Font fntOther = new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 16);
private final Font fntTitle = new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 20);
private LoginController controller;

public LoginScreen() {
    this.controller = new LoginController(this);
    this.setTitle("Login");
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    setUpComponents();
}

private void setUpComponents() {

    lblTitle = new JLabel("Burrito Business");
    lblUsername = new JLabel("Van reg: ");
    lblPassword = new JLabel("Password: ");

    txtVanReg = new JTextField();
    txtPassword = new JPasswordField();

    btnLogin = new JButton("Login");
    btnCancel = new JButton("Cancel");

    btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            controller.loginRequested(txtVanReg.getText(), txtPassword.getPassword());
        }
    });

    btnCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            controller.loginCancelled();

        }
    });


    pnlCenter = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 3));
    pnlNorth = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

    pnlCenter.add(lblUsername);
    pnlCenter.add(txtVanReg);
    pnlCenter.add(lblPassword);
    pnlCenter.add(txtPassword);
    pnlCenter.add(btnLogin);
    pnlCenter.add(btnCancel);

    pnlNorth.add(lblTitle);
    setFonts();

    this.add(pnlNorth, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    this.add(pnlCenter, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 150));
    this.setResizable(false);

}

private void setFonts() {

    lblTitle.setFont(fntTitle);

    lblUsername.setFont(fntOther);
    lblPassword.setFont(fntOther);
    txtVanReg.setFont(fntOther);
    txtPassword.setFont(fntOther);

    btnLogin.setFont(fntOther);
    btnCancel.setFont(fntOther);

}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see java.util.Observer#update(java.util.Observable, java.lang.Object)
 */
public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
    if (o instanceof DBUserAuth && ((Boolean) arg).booleanValue() == true) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), "Login successful");

    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), "Login failed");
    }

}

public char[] getPassword() {
    return this.txtPassword.getPassword();
}

public String getVanReg() {
    return this.txtVanReg.getText();
}

public void close() {
    this.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
}

}
```

The Controller:

```
public class LoginController {
private DBUserAuth dbConnection;
private LoginScreen view;

public LoginController(LoginScreen view) {
    dbConnection = new DBUserAuth();
    this.view = view;
    dbConnection.addObserver(view);
}

public void loginRequested(String van_reg, char[] password) {
        String pass = "";

        for (char a : password) {
            pass += a;
        }

        if (dbConnection.checkUser(van_reg, pass)) {
            StaffMenu aMenu = new StaffMenu(van_reg);
            aMenu.setVisible(true);
            view.close();
        }


}

public void loginCancelled() {
    view.close();
}

}
```

The Model:

```
public class DBUserAuth extends Observable {

private Properties props;
private Connection con;
private String url, password, username;
private PreparedStatement loginAuthStatement, addTruckStatement;
private ResultSet results;

/**
 * Loads the properties file and gets the url, username and the password
 * from the file. Then goes on to open a connection to the database.
 */
public DBUserAuth() {

    // 1. Load properties in
    props = new Properties();
    ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    InputStream stream = loader.getResourceAsStream("prop.properties");

    try {
        props.load(stream);
        url = props.getProperty("db.url");
        username = props.getProperty("db.username");
        password = props.getProperty("db.password");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Failed to load properties");
    }

}

/**
 * Used to connect to the DB
 * 
 * @return True if success, false otherwise
 */
private boolean openConnection() {
    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        // connect to the db
        System.out.println("Connected to the DB");
        return true;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Failed to connect to the DB");
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Used to close connection to the DB
 * 
 * @return True if success, false otherwise
 */
private boolean closeConnection() {
    try {
        con.close();
        return true;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * 
 * @param password
 *            the proposed password i.e. the password to check
 * @return
 */
public boolean checkUser(String username, String password) {
    long time13 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long time14;
    try {
        openConnection();
        loginAuthStatement = con.prepareStatement(
                "SELECT Van_reg_no, Hashed_Password FROM Food_Truck WHERE Van_reg_no LIKE ? ORDER BY Van_reg_no ASC");
        loginAuthStatement.setString(1, "%" + username + "%");

        results = loginAuthStatement.executeQuery();

        results.beforeFirst();

        while (results.next()) {
            String reg = results.getString(1);
            String hashPassword = results.getString(2);

            if (reg.equals(username) && BCrypt.checkpw(password, hashPassword)) {
                System.out.println("Login passed");

                time14 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                System.out.println("Total login time: " + (time14 - time13) + " miliseconds.");
                setChanged();
                notifyObservers(new Boolean(true));
                return true;
            }
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("SQL for user auth. failed");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        closeConnection();
    }
    setChanged();
    notifyObservers(new Boolean(false));

    time14 = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println("Total login time: " + (time14 - time13) + " miliseconds.");
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: @User59 Patience please. Good reviews will take time.

Comment: If you don't mind, I have edited a question — indentation fixed;)

Comment: @maxkoryukov I serioously mind your edit.

Comment: @maxkoryukov You may be interested in reading [Removing leading white space in question code blocks](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6841/removing-leading-white-space-in-question-code-blocks).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for sharing the code.

### MVC

The basic concept of MVC is:

- the model does not know of neither the controller nor the view .

  It consists of *data structure* classes only. It should only contain logic to notify others about changes. It should define its own *Listener* interfaces and provide methods to register to change events. The Java-8 *Property* feature provides that out of the box.

  Any logic to *persist* the model (to a database, the file system,a web service or alike) belongs to the controller layer.
- the controller works on the model and does not know of the view.

  This means your controller should not get the view as parameter and it should not create view related objects (the  `StaffMenu` in particular).

  Usually the view does not register for events at the controller. It reacts either on the value(s) returned by a method call or the Exception thrown.
- the view displays values from the model and manipulates them through the controller.

  This means the view registers itself for changes at the model and calls methods in the controller upon user input.

> Your assertion that the Controller should persist the data is non-standard. See SoftwareEngineering.SE and Wikipedia for example. The Model is responsible for data persistence, either directly or by calling something else to handle it. At most, the Controller may trigger the shift to persistent storage. For example, by processing a "Save" button press and notifying the Model. – mdfst13

Some resources state that *persistence layer* and *business logic* are part of the (domain) model.

Usually the (data) Model has a very tight coupling to the persistence layer.

I.e.: There are lots of frameworks out there which allow us to generate DTO classes from a persistence model (XSD, JSON, database tables) or vice versa (by adding persistence specific annotations to the DTO classes).

This reduces the *Controller* layer to pure boilerplate code doing nothing else than translation user input to model actions (and vice versa). When looking at Swing the result would be that the Controller is completely integrated in the View represented by the many anonymous inner classes we register as *listeners* to Swings GUI components.

---

### Other findings

#### Naming

Finding good names is the hardest part in programming. So always take your time to think about your identifier names.

On the bright side you follow the Java naming conventions. (except `van_reg`). This is a good starting point.

But you should have your *method* names start with a verb in its *present tense*.
E.g.:  `loginRequested` should be named `requestLogin`.

Also you should use exact names. 
Your variable `dbConnection` is of type `DBUserAuth` which *not* a database connection but uses a database connection itself.

Also: avoid single letter variable names or abbreviations. 
There is no penalty for long names. 
Its always better to be a bit "wordy" then being to short leaving room for interpretations. 
But beware of writing "novels" on the other hand...

#### Wrong inheritance

We use inheritance if we want to change the *behavior* of a base class. This means we want to *overwrite* a base class's method or *add* a new one.

Your view extends `JPanel` without extending its behavior. You only configure it which could be done on a normal `JFrame` instance.

#### Dependency Injection / Inversion of Control

Your code uses some dependencies.
Eg.: your controller class uses an instance of the `DBUserAuth` class.

This instance is created in the constructor of the `LoginController` class.
This makes it hard to change the way your user authentication works. 
What if you want to switch to tho a file based authentication, or to a web service?

You should pass the `DBUserAuth` instance as a *parameter* to the constructor.

Preferably this parameter would be declared as an *interface* that defines the methods called by  the `LoginController`. The `DBUserAuth` class would then implement this interface.

#### SRP/SoC

Your violations of the MVC pattern are almost all consequences of the violation of the *single responsibility pattern* ([SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)) and the *separation of concerns* pattern ([SoC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)).

eg: Your method `loginRequested` does 2 things:

1. call the user check in the database
2. create the `staffMenu`

The latter is clearly a responsibility of the view.

Comment: Another one benefit of the DI/IoC ­— mocking, stubbing and easy testing. Often, **testing**, and not the "switch to file-based auth", is the first, who requires to use DI

Comment: @mdfst13 Thanks for improving my answer, I updated it.

Answer (score 2):

## Always use proper and consistent indentation

> ```
> public class LoginScreen extends JFrame implements Observer {
> private JLabel lblTitle, lblUsername, lblPassword;
> private JTextField txtVanReg;
> private JPasswordField txtPassword;
> // ...
> }
> ```

Statements coming after an opening brace usually `{` should be indented with another number of whitespaces:

```
   public class LoginScreen extends JFrame implements Observer {
// vvvv
       private JLabel lblTitle, lblUsername, lblPassword;
       private JTextField txtVanReg;
       private JPasswordField txtPassword;
   // ...
   }
```

Also any style of indentation should be used consistently. E.g. here you were using a  different style:

```
   public LoginScreen() {
// vvvv
       this.controller = new LoginController(this);
       this.setTitle("Login");
       this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

       setUpComponents();
   }
```

You may claim that this is a minor point regarding improvements of the correctly applied MVC pattern implementation, or other concerns about logical and semantical improvements.

Though that's a basic concern you should master in your (whatever) coding style, since it's a ***key feature*** for readability and maintainability of your code.

---

<sub>**Note:**

There are even languages like *python*, which just enforce that to get your statements syntactically correct.</sub>

Comment: I am not sure, but the question is **not only about codestyle**... Probably, it is enough to point to wrong indentation in comments (you have done this already though;) Moreover it is so easy to fix style in the question..

Comment: @maxkoryukov Sure that question isn't only about code style. If you would have read all of the comments at the OP, you'd get a grip why I was writing that answer.

Comment: @maxkoryukov As per the [help/on-topic], any and all aspects of the code are subject to review. Comments are reserved for seeking clarification to the question, and must not be used for critiquing the code.

Comment: yeah, you are definitely right: `Every answer must make at least one insightful observation about the code in the question`. Now I know a little bit more;) This answer contains recommendations about consistent indenting, so probably, someone will find this useful;) Just one problem: **I have edited the original question**, because author told, that indentation eaten by eclipse, and my edits are minor.. there is an article about editing questions...

Comment: @maxkoryukov I rolled back your edit. If you would have seen the edit history, you would have been aware, that I edited the question already a 1st time to cover that specific point of the OP. This didn't concern the valid indentation. Also editing in a way that it invalidates existing answers isn't really helpful for anyone.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ as you wish - rollback and make the answer hard-to-read again, but you know this doesn't help others a lot.. no matter though, bcz I think **style is a task for linter, find decent code editor, and forget about indentation forever**

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, `Just check my profile ` — thanks, but no))) But it is very hard to mention you. And I have no idea, how your nickname sounds like) May be something like `user818210`, or `awesomecoder` - I will never know))))

Comment: @maxkoryukov _"But it is very hard to mention you"_ Since when it was hard to type _@_ in the comment box?? :-P

Answer (score 1):

## There is one suggestion:

In the `LoginController.loginRequested` method, replace

```
String pass = "";

for (char a : password) {
    pass += a;
}
```

with

```
String pass = String.valueOf(password);
```

This will help you shorten your code.